# Load from more 2 class in 1 swift UISPLITVIEWCONTROLLER

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, class, uisplitviewcontroller

I try to find information how to load this data from another class I have a `UISplitViewController` and a lot of information inside I try to load Theta from 2 different classes in the 1 class can somebody help me please ?

```
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Chocolate", "Hard", "Other"]
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

candies = [

//I want to load the first2 candy from another Swift class

Candy(category:"go", name:"slow"),
Candy(category:"run", name:"feast"),

//and the least 2 Candy to load from another Swift class

Candy(category:"deanc", name:"good"),
Candy(category:"fly", name:"whery feast"),
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard for me to understand what you want to do. But let me give it a shot:

```
let candies1 = [Candy(category:"go", name:"slow"),
Candy(category:"run", name:"feast")]

let candies2 =  [Candy(category:"deanc", name:"good"),
Candy(category:"fly", name:"whery feast")]
```

Now you can use candies1 and candies2 in whatever class and func you want. 
Let me know what you think

Comment: sory my english is not so good i tray to load  like this

let candies = [hir  data from class 1 and class 2 ]

bicos i have like Candy(..) about 3000 example and when i giv in 1 swift its a lof of data in 1 file dosen't work good